# How to count the number of values in an array for all the rows in a DataFrame in python?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, arraylist, count

I have a DataFrame with a column named players, I want to count all the players playing in that round for all the rows.

[image: This is how it looks like.]

These values- simple5dd1bd72e209cf05624291cd, simple62d6fd3.....

Some of these rows have 3 values some have 4 some have 5. I want to count the number of values one row has. Every one of them is separated by comma (**,**) and start with **simple**.

> ```
> df['PlayersCount'] = df['players'].str.count('simple')
> ```

I tried using this but I am getting NaN in PlayersCount Column.

```
   tags = df2['players'].str.split(',')
   df2['PlayersCount'] = len(tags)
```

I also tried this but it gives me 20777.

Sorry I could not make a sample dataframe for you guys, as I do not know how to.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df2['PlayersCount'] = df2['players'].str.len()
```

Or:

```
df2['PlayersCount'] = df2["Player"].str.count(",") + 1
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, try df2['PlayersCount'] = df2["Player"].str.count(",") + 1